# why can't I assign null to a particular index of Char Array?

Tags: java

I am trying to assign `null` to a index in char array `a[i] = null`. I am getting type mismatch. What should give to keep that position `null`.

Comment: Why do you want to make it `null`?

Answer (score 6):

`char`s are primitive data types, and are consequently not nullable in Java.

> `null` may be assigned to any variable, except variables of primitive types.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

What are you trying to accomplish by nulling out those positions? If you want to indicate "no value," you could use [a `null` *character*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00/index.htm) instead:

```
a[i] = '\0';
```

...but [there's probably a better approach to your problem overall.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `null` any variable,  except  `primitive` datatype

```
String s = null;  //true because String is object
```

Answer (score 0):

char is value type so they cannot hold reference...null can be allocated to reference type only.

```
char and other primitive datatypes can hold value only.
a[i] = 'a'; // allowed
a = null; // allowed   
a[i] = null; // not allowed


int a = 2; //allowed
int a = null; // not allowed  

string a = null; //allowed because string array of characters.
```